# SQL Select newest (public) post of each user

Tags: sql, subquery, unique

An example of the data could look like:

| username | tweet | is_public | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| catelie | tweet1 | 1 | 2021-06-14 |
| urs | tweet1 | 1 | 2021-06-15 |
| nik | firstlast | 1 | 2021-06-15 |
| urs | lasttweet | 1 | 2021-06-23 |
| nik | empty | 0 | 2021-06-23 |

To select all ***public tweets***:

```
 WHERE is_public = 1
```

To select ***newest tweet per user*** I was inspired by [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-partition-by-another-column-in-mys/27802817#27802817) so I got:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM post
  LEFT JOIN posts as postdouble
    ON posts.created_at < postdouble.created_at AND posts.username = postdouble.username
WHERE postdouble.username IS NULL
```

To select ***newest and public tweet per user*** (mix up these two statements) I'm lost by some SubSubQueries

```
SELECT posts.username, posts.tweet, posts.is_public, posts.created_at, postdouble.username as userd, postdouble.tweet as tweetd, postdouble.is_public as ispublicd, postdouble.created_at as createdatd FROM posts
  LEFT JOIN posts as postdouble
    ON posts.created_at < (
         SELECT MAX(posts.created_at) FROM posts WHERE is_public = 1
      )
    AND posts.username = postdouble.username
-- WHERE postdouble.username IS NULL
```

urs is selected right (empty entities in doubles) but that's the only thing thats right. Please help me with some debugging.thx^^lg

Comment: . . I'm a little confused on what your queries have to do with the question you have asked.

Comment: My query contains the "newest tweet per user" (from the link I posted and that contains the "p1.created_at<p2.created_at"-approach). My last query also contains my own approach with MAX(). The correct answer to my question skipped the "p1.created_at<p2.created_at" and only use the MAX()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this.  You can use a correlated subquery, but you don't need an additional `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE p.created_at = (SELECT MAX(p2.created_at)
                      FROM posts p2
                      WHERE p2.is_public = 1 AND
                            p2.username = p.username
                     ) AND
      p.is_public = 1;
```

The correlation clause makes sure it is for the same user.

For optimal performance, you want an index on `posts(username, public, created_at)`.

Comment: thx, me start loving stackoverflow :) I'll mark you answer as cvorrect as soon I'm allowed to mark it (I'm too new here to mark or upvote anythig now)

Comment: With your answer I "corrected" my Code:

SELECT posts.username, posts.tweet, posts.is_public, posts.created_at, postdouble.username as userd, postdouble.tweet as tweetd, postdouble.is_public as ispublicd, postdouble.created_at as createdatd FROM posts
  LEFT JOIN posts as postdouble
    ON posts.username = postdouble.username
    AND posts.created_at < (
        SELECT MAX(postdouble.created_at) FROM posts WHERE postdouble.is_public = 1
      )
WHERE postdouble.username IS NULL
AND posts.is_public = 1

BUT, yeah, all criteria (is_public = 1 for example) needs to listed twice^^lg

Comment: @DarioDS . . . This answer does not have a `JOIN`.

Comment: yeah, and you answer also contains no GROUP BY(). (In compare of the solution that was marked as "correct" linked above ). I just posted my "working-code" in full compare of your shorter answer (seems both run in +-10% same speed, and for sure I addopted your shortening to my production)! thx again (and I now was able to mark your answer as the correct one)^^lg

Comment: I think they run at same speed as all criteria (is_public = 1 for example) needs to listed twice (in my code and also in your shortening). Or are there a solution (without "window function" nor the "top 1 with ties") where you only have to list "is_public = 1" once?

Answer (score 0):

One other easy way would be to use a `window function` to pick off the required rows

```
select * from (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by username order by created_at desc) rn
    from posts
    where is_public=1
)p
where rn=1
```

You could also in this instance get the same result using `top 1 with ties`

```
select top (1)  with ties *, Row_Number() over(partition by username order by created_at desc) rn
from posts
where is_public=1
order by rn
```